# Ubuntu server 16.04.1 LTS (grub-pc : Depends: grub-common) error

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-45-generic i686) for a number of years. Since week the server will not update. I just get the error "The following packages have unmet dependencies". I have tried `apt-get -f install` & `auto clean` & `auto remove` but still the same error.

```
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.

grub-pc : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.7) but 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.6 is installed
grub-pc-bin : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.7) but 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.6 is installed
grub2-common : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.7) but 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.6 is installed
```

Comment: What version of Ununtu server are you really running? If 'for a number of years', this could not be 16.04.1!

Comment: I started with Ubuntu Server 12.04 a few years back then upgrade Ubuntu Server14.04. Last year I upgraded to Ubuntu Server 16.04. Still on 16.04 now.